# GHC make explicit forall mandatory

Tags: haskell, ghc

The language extension `ExplicitForall` makes it possible but not required to bind type variables with `forall`.

For example, the following program compiles

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

-- cps1.hs

-- non-cps definition of add
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y

-- cps definition of add
add_cps :: forall r . Int -> Int -> (Int -> r) -> r
add_cps x y k = k (add x y)
```

However, the following program without an explicit quantifier for `r` also compiles.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

-- cps2.hs

-- non-cps definition of add
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add x y = x + y

-- cps definition of add
add_cps :: Int -> Int -> (Int -> r) -> r
add_cps x y k = k (add x y)
```

Is there some combination of language extensions or compiler flags that can make the second program fail to compile?

Comment: I don't think this is possible to achieve, with the current GHC.

Comment: I'm interested as to why you'd want the second to fail?

Comment: @AJFarmar I could see it being useful to avoid confusing errors when you have `ScopedTypeVariables` turned on but forgot to bring a variable into scope with a `forall`.

Comment: Daniel's rationale is much better. I'm writing a generator for some Haskell code and want to the output to be processed with options that are as strict as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, GHC currently does not have tooling for that.